# How to change legend icon on hover Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, legend, onhover

I am trying to customize a chartjs legend so that when you hover over a legend item, the icon/point style will change. See screenshot [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV2iN.png). Is this possible?

I am trying different things with the onHover property but am not having success.

```
 legend: {
            display: true,
            onHover: function (event, legendItem, legend) {
            //Change Point style to icon
            },
            onLeave: function (e) {
            //Change back to normal
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can update the pointStyle of the given dataset you are hovering, you can pass any of the predefined pointStyles of chart.js or an image as decribed in the documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/elements.html#point-styles)

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true
        },
        onHover: (evt, item, legend) => {
          legend.chart.data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].pointStyle = 'rectRot'
          legend.chart.update();
        },
        onLeave: (evt, item, legend) => {
          legend.chart.data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].pointStyle = ''
          legend.chart.update();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Proscrypt: If you think, this is the answer that solves your problem, please mark it as accepted (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409).